# Send a variable from popup.js to background.js in Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Before I start - yes I know there are some answers to similar questions, but none of them are complete. I.e. you cannot use the info in the answers without documents that weren't included in the question.

So I'm trying to set up a scaffold to use in chrome extensions where I can type something in a field in the popup and it is stored in the background. I will probably then use this variable to call an API on the field (say a ZIP code for a weather app for instance).

**All I am trying to do here is set the badge text to the message entered on the popup.**

I've tried to use the code in other answers to this question, but I haven't been able to get anything to work, which is why I am keeping this very simple.

**manifest.json** (nothing crazy here):

```
{
  "name": "Popup to Background Communication",
  "description": "Chrome Extension Scaffolding for Communication between
    the popup and the background script.",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "version": "1.0",
  "background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"],
    "persistent": false
  },
  "browser_action": {
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  },
  "permissions": [
    "storage",
    "activeTab"
  ]
}
```

**popup.html** (shows a field with a sumbit button)

```
<!doctype html>
<html>

  <div class="field_entry">
    <p>Enter Message to be Sent:</p>
    <form id = "messageForm">
      <input type="text" id="messageToSend" />
      <input type="submit"/>
    </form>
  </div>

</html>
```

**popup.js** (listens for the submit and calls a function from background):

```
function sendToBackground() {
  var messageFromForm = document.getElementById("messageToSend");
  var background = chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage();
  background.setBadgeToMessage(messageFromForm);
}

document.getElementById('messageForm')
            .addEventListener('submit', sendToBackground);
```

**background.js** (holds the variable to change to the message from popup)

```
var badge = "0";

function setBadgeToMessage(msg){
  badge = msg;
  chrome.browserAction.setBadgeText(badge + "");
};
```

Nothing happens when I submit. I think what is wrong is that I am accessing a variable from popup.js that is local to background.js, but it seems like it should at least change the version copied to popup.js and change the badge.

Any help would be super appreciated. I've been beating my head against the wall on this for 2 days and it seems like a super simple issue.

Answer (score 3):

You're almost there. However, you cannot pass a Element as a message to the Chrome API. The docs for `browserAction.setBadgeText` specify an object. Do it like so:

```
function sendToBackground() {
  var messageFromForm = document.getElementById("messageToSend").value;
 chrome.runtime.getBackgroundPage((background) => background.setBadgeToMessage(messageFromForm));

  ...
}

...

function setBadgeToMessage(msg){
  badge = msg;
  chrome.browserAction.setBadgeText({ text : badge });
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! However, it's still not working.

I'm getting the following on the console: "Navigated to chrome-extension://ondgmbecifbponmienpbdjcoonkfclle/popup.html?"

Is it possible to change variables in background.js by calling it this way? Maybe I'm just going about this entirely wrong.

Comment: @stringgy Two things: 1) call event.preventDefault() in submit handler, or don't use a submit type button 2) background page expects a calback, sorry I missed that before. Will edit my answer. With these two things I was able to get it to work.

Comment: I still was not able to get it to work sadly. I added event.preventDefault into the the sendToBackround() function and changed the call to getbackground to the way it is in your edited comment, but still nothing. This is the full contents of popup.js now:



function sendToBackground() {
  event.preventDefault();
  var messageFromForm = document.getElementById("messageToSend").value;
  chrome.runtime.getBackgroundPage((background) => background.setBadgeToMessage(messageFromForm));
};

document.getElementById("messageForm")
            .addEventListener("submit", sendToBackground());

Comment: @stringgy Corrections: `function sendToBackground(event) { ` and `document.getElementById("messageForm") .addEventListener("submit", sendToBackground)`

Comment: I didn't look at it over American Independence day, but coming back to the project, I'm sorry to say that, even with your last changes, it's still not working. 

I've ordered a book on javascript because I clearly need to get a lot more familiar.